# Make a data frame of daily values from hourly data

Tags: r

So my data looks like this

```
station valid           tmpf
LFMN    1988-01-01 0:00 50.18
LFMN    1988-01-01 1:00 50
LFMN    1988-01-01 1:15 50
LFMN    1988-01-01 1:30 50
LFMN    1988-01-01 2:00 50
```

I'd like to have the daily temperature value presented something like

```
station day     daily
LFMN    1988-01-01 51
LFMN    1988-01-02 49
```

It seems simple enough but no solutions posted here work. I've tried using zoo, dplyr, plys, and... nothing.
When I do this

```
g %>% mutate(date=as.Date(valid)) %>% group_by(date) %>% summarize(daily=mean(tmpf))
```

It returns a two column dataset with the correct formats for the day column and everything NA in daily

Comment: Did you meant the `valid` column as `NA`

Comment: See if the `tmpf` is numeric. If so, use the `mean(tmpf, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Do you have `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr` ? Try `g1 <- g %>% group_by(date = as.Date(valid)) %>%  dplyr::summarize(daily=mean(tmpf, na.rm = TRUE))` The result is in `g1`.

Answer (score 0):

`mean` can return `NA` if there is at least one `NA` value.  There is an option to remove the `NA` element in `mean` i.e. `na.rm` which is by default `FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
g %>% 
    mutate(date=as.Date(valid)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarize(daily=mean(tmpf, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Well I have a real question now - performing the line has started to change the values. The data in the daily column is at least 30 degrees higher than it should be after running that line.

Comment: @Nadka Not clear about that statement.  I answered your original question.

Comment: the  `g %>% 
    mutate(date=as.Date(valid)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarize(daily=mean(tmpf, na.rm = TRUE))` doesn't work as intended because it changed the temperature values. For example, it produces `2 1988-01-02  76.6 ` output when it should be `2 1988-01-02 49.9`